# Как во vue.js сохранить текст, введённый в input, в переменную, чтобы оттуда сохранить её в store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Пытаюсь учить, 2-й день завис на одном месте. Как во vue.js сохранить текст введённый в `input` в перемеренную, что бы оттуда сохранить её в `store`, а потом из `store` записывать в `value`. В общем сохранять введённое значение и перезаписывать его при изменении. Но мне хотя бы понять как его сохранять для дальнейшей передачи в `store`.

`v-on:input="saveUserName"` - вот тут я отслеживаю событие ввода текста

```
<f7-list-input
  label="Username"
  name="username"
  placeholder="Username"
  type="text"
  :value="userName"
  @input="username = $event.target.value"
  v-on:input="saveUserName"
/>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      saveUserName,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    signIn() {
      const self = this;
      const app = self.$f7;
      const router = self.$f7router;
      router.back();
      app.dialog.alert(`Username: ${self.username}<br>Password: ${self.password}`, () => {
        router.back();
      });
    },
    saveUserName(){
        alert(self.userName);
    }
  },
  computed:{
     userName(){
         return this.$store.state.userName;
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        userNameStor:'',
        userPasswordStor:''
    },
    mutations:{
        saveName(state){

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Для двусторонней связки элемента ввода и переменной существует директива `v-model`

Comment: я пробовал через него, но я всё равно не могу найти нигде как это значение перенести в скрипт.  v-model="takeUserName"  ,а получить его через return в data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой пример:

```js
Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    value: ""
  },
  actions: {
    setValue: ({commit}, value) => {
      commit("setValue", value);
      //localStorage.setItem("value", value)
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setValue: (state, value) => state.value = value
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    input_value: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.value
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.dispatch("setValue", value)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.0/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="input_value">
  <div>{{ $store.state.value }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как в самом сторе переменную записать что бы можно было дальше её передать в localstorage ?                                                                                                                                     `state:{
  userNameStor: 'input_value',
 },
 mutations:{
  saveName(state, payload){
  state.input_value = payload;
 }`

Comment: @Dio дополнил ответ

Comment: При попытках в Input ввести текст в инпуте выдаёт "[object InputEvent]"

Comment: @Dio при использовании `v-model` у input НЕ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ` :value` и `@input`/`v-on:input`

Comment: У меня его и нет вот мой инпут       `<f7-list-input
        label="Fix"
        placeholder="Enter some text"
        type="text"
        v-model="input_value"
      />`

Comment: @Dio сделал сниппет из примера, все работает. Попробуй простой input вместо f7-list-input, возможно в нем дело

Comment: да из-за фрэймвёрка проблема была

Answer (score 2):

1. Не вижу где у тебя v-model у input
2. После того как создаешь v-model у input в методе можешь написать this.$store.dispatch("saveName", YOUR_V_MODEL_INPUT)

Пример как у меня это организованно

файле store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from "vuex"

Vue.use(Vuex)


export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        languages: ''
    },
    getters: {
        languages: stete => stete.languages

    },
    actions: {
        loadLanguages(contex, payload) {
            contex.commit('loadLanguages', payload)
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        loadLanguages(state, payload) {
            state.languages = payload
        },

    },
    modules: {} //maybe we will be used in future
})
```

для того чтоб записать в переменую в store можно с любого файла vue из methods, computed и т.д. Первый параметр это переменая из store, а второй это переменую что ты отправляешь в Store

```
 this.$store.dispatch("loadLanguages", Trans.currentLanguage)
```

получить переменую из Store в любом файле можно так.

```
computed:{
            language(){
                return  this.$store.getters.languages
            }
        }
```

Comment: Мне тут сказали "v-model is a shorcut for using @input and :value at the same time. Don't use it with :value and @input."